# Querying the active palette from grease pencil vertex color palette via python

Tags: python, palettes

Is there a way to query the name of the currently active palette shown when you click in the color swatch on the drawing bar in the main UI when using Grease Pencil's vertex color mode?

Alternatively, perhaps querying the palettes in the overall scene would work, but I'd like to able to distinguish which one is actively being used.

`bpy.data.grease_pencils.data.palettes`

gets me a list of the palettes but neither the returned BlendDataPalettes nor the Palette objects in it seem to have an active attribute that can be queried. I also see we can get the active color within the palette, but what about the active palette itself?

Answer (score 0):

The active palette is available in the tool settings:

`bpy.context.tool_settings.gpencil_paint.palette`